# How to change PHP Smarty plugin template file extension in NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, smarty, netbeans-6.9, netbeans-plugins

NetBeans uses PHP Smarty Framework plugin for *.tpl files. Is it possible to change this to *.htm? I use .htm extension for smarty templates and would like to benefit from this PHP Smarty plugin. How can I do that?

Comment: http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqCliOpen

Comment: It's not what I am looking for. I want PHP Smarty plugin to interpret my *.htm files as smarty templates (so e. g. it won't mark curly braces as errors).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In NetBeans (with the PHP Smarty Framework plugin installed):

1. Click on the *Tools* menu, and select *Options*
2. Click on *Miscellaneous* located toward the right side of the top icon bar of the Options dialog.
3. Click on the *Files* tab.
4. In the *File Extension* combo-box field, select **htm**.
5. In the *Associated File Type (MIME)* field, change the value to **TPL (text/tpl)**.
6. Click *OK*

To restore the original behavior, repeat the above steps, except select *HTML Files (text/html)* in step 5.

Comment: Note that this does not *change* the behavior from .tpl to .htm, but instead adds .htm to the list of extensions treated as template files.

Comment: I didn't notice this answer before. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is it possible to do the same with *.inc.php extension? I cannot seem to be able to add that to the list of 'File Extensions'

Comment: @serbanghita I believe the answer to your question is no. AFAIK Netbeans only recognizes the last extension. On the other hand, adding the "php" extension would treat all .php files (including all  .inc.php files) as Smarty Templates. That, of course, may not be what you want to have happen.

Answer (score 1):

I found http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqCplusPlusDefaultExtensions
, unfortunately it's only for C/C++ .

The php-tab *should* have something like it as well...