# May I change .tpl file at opencart theme to .php?

Tags: php, netbeans, opencart

The Opencart theme files have the extension .tpl, but inside them is php code.
In Netbeans, php code inside .tpl file is not highlighted as usual and the autocomplete is also missing.
How can I have the .tpl file acting as a .php one regarding highlighting and autocompletion?

Comment: Several options:

1. PHP lets you define custom extensions for files that should be considered as PHP.
2. You can always do a URL rewrite on the server level(nginx, apache)

Answer (score 4):

you should not do that because that require systemfile modification instead you can add the file extension to netbeans to take this file type as php

here the steps

Open Tools and Select Options.
Select Miscellaneous tab.
Select Files sub-tab thing.
Click on New file extension and enter tpl.
Select the mime type.
Click OK. Done!

taken from here

[How to change PHP Smarty plugin template file extension in NetBeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353069/how-to-change-php-smarty-plugin-template-file-extension-in-netbeans)